# Type Mismatch Error in VBA UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a "type mismatch" error with my code and I'm not sure where it's coming from. The wonderful VBA editor doesn't tell me where it is and I was wondering if I could get some help tracking it down. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub refresh_Click()

Dim random As Integer
Dim passedSheet As Worksheets
    Set passedSheet = Sheets("Org Chart - JC")
Dim inputSheet As Worksheets
    Set inputSheet = Sheets("Analytics - JC")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

random = createHistogram(Sheets("Org Chart - JC").Range("A2:A1000"), 3, 1, passedSheet, inputSheet)
random = createHistogram(Sheets("Org Chart - JC").Range("C2:C1000"), 3, 4, passedSheet, inputSheet)
random = createHistogram(Sheets("Org Chart - JC").Range("D2:D1000"), 3, 7, passedSheet, inputSheet)
random = createHistogram(Sheets("Org Chart - JC").Range("E2:E1000"), 3, 10, passedSheet, inputSheet)
random = createHistogram(Sheets("Org Chart - JC").Range("F2:F1000"), 3, 13, passedSheet, inputSheet)
random = createHistogram(Sheets("Org Chart - JC").Range("H2:H1000"), 3, 16, passedSheet, inputSheet)

'Format the width of all columns'
With Range("A:Q")
    .Select
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

With Range("C1, F1, I1, L1, O1").EntireColumn
    .ColumnWidth = 2
End With

Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

And here is the function of createHistogram:

```
Function createHistogram(rng As Range, pasteRow As Integer, pasteColumn As Integer, passedSheet As Worksheets, inputSheet As Worksheets)

Dim rngCount As Integer
Dim uniqueResultsCount As Integer

'Get info from "passedSheet" sheet'
passedSheet.Select
rngCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng)
rng.Select
Selection.Copy
inputSheet.Select
Cells(pasteRow, pasteColumn).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Remove duplicates leaving unique values and count remaining values'
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(pasteRow, pasteColumn), Cells(pasteRow + 200, pasteColumn)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
uniqueResultsCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(pasteRow, pasteColumn), Cells(pasteRow + 200, pasteColumn)))
'    MsgBox ("uniqueResultsCounter has a value of: " & uniqueResultsCount)

'Count all of the existing values in the "passedSheet" sheet'
For i = 1 To uniqueResultsCount
    Cells(pasteRow - 1 + i, pasteColumn + 1).Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Cells(pasteRow - 1 + i, pasteColumn))
Next i

'Clear existing formating for selection'
With Range(Cells(pasteRow, pasteColumn), Cells(pasteRow + uniqueResultsCount + 200, pasteColumn + 1))
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    .Font.Bold = xlFalse
End With

'Create new formatting for selection'
With Range(Cells(pasteRow, pasteColumn), Cells(pasteRow + uniqueResultsCount - 1, pasteColumn + 1))
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Font.Bold = xlFalse
End With
With Range(Cells(pasteRow, pasteColumn), Cells(pasteRow + uniqueResultsCount - 1, pasteColumn + 1))
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

'Sort the column from A to Z'
Range(Cells(pasteRow, pasteColumn), Cells(pasteRow + uniqueResultsCount - 1, pasteColumn + 1)).Sort _
    key1:=Cells(pasteRow, pasteColumn)

createHistogram = 1

End Function
```

I know some of my variable names aren't the best, but nobody else was supposed to see this code.

I think the major error is with the `passedSheet` and `inputSheet` variables. I'm still getting used to VBA and I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the difference between sheets and worksheets is and when to use each.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You have this in your function declaration: `passedSheet As Worksheets, inputSheet As Worksheets` where you are asking for `Worksheets` (plural) instead of `Worksheet` (singular).  Try using the singular and see if you still get the error.

Comment: You sir, are a saint. It's crazy how we can stare at code for hours and miss something as simple as that. Thanks again, @tigeravatar!

Comment: FYI use the Debug | Compile (or make use of `Option Explicit` in each code module to help point out (and avoid) errors like these.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are making them type worksheets instead of worksheet. Might not be the answer, but try it out and let me know.